# ASP.NET Mvc3/VS2010 error: An item with the same key has already been added

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I've been trying to add a Controller in my Project, but I've been getting the error

```
An item with the same key has already been added.
```

while doing so.

I'm still a beginner at this, so I might have not noticed something, but I don't see any duplicate keys in my model.This is my database's diagram to get the general idea of what I'm trying to do:

[image: Database Diagram]

I'm using `Applications` as the `Model Class` and `ApplicationServices` as the `data Context Class` while trying to create my `ApplicationController` and getting the error

```
An item with the same key has already been added.
```

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

The models I've created are the following:

**Entity.cs:**

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace PostGraduate.Models
{
    public class ApplicationServices : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Application.Users> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Application.Addresses> Addresses { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Application.Applications> Applications { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Application.ForeignLanguages> ForeignLanguages { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Application.Gmat> Gmat { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Application.PostGradStudies> PostGradStudies { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Application.PreGradStudies> PreGradStudies { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Application.Schoolarships> Schoolarships { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Application.Users>().HasKey(a => a.UserId);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Application.Addresses>().HasKey(a => a.Addresses_Id);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Application.Applications>().HasKey(a => a.Applications_Id);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Application.Applications>().Property(a => a.Applications_Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Application.ForeignLanguages>().HasKey(a => a.ForeignLanguages_Id);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Application.Gmat>().HasKey(a => a.Gmat_Id);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Application.Gmat>().Property(a => a.Gmat_Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Application.PostGradStudies>().HasKey(a => a.PostGradStudies_Id);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Application.PostGradStudies>().Property(a => a.PostGradStudies_Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Application.PreGradStudies>().HasKey(a => a.PreGradStudies_Id);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Application.Schoolarships>().HasKey(a => a.Schoolarships_Id);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Application.Schoolarships>().Property(a => a.Schoolarships_Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Application.Users>().HasRequired(a => a.Applications).WithRequiredPrincipal(i => i.Users);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Application.Applications>().HasMany(a => a.Addresses).WithRequired(i => i.Applications).HasForeignKey(i => i.Application_Id);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Application.Applications>().HasMany(a => a.ForeignLanguages).WithRequired(i => i.Applications).HasForeignKey(i => i.Application_Id);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Application.Applications>().HasOptional(a => a.Gmat).WithRequired(i => i.Applications);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Application.Applications>().HasOptional(a => a.PostGradStudies).WithRequired(i => i.Applications);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Application.Applications>().HasMany(a => a.PreGradStudies).WithRequired(i => i.Applications).HasForeignKey(i => i.Application_Id);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Application.Applications>().HasOptional(a => a.Schoolarships).WithRequired(i => i.Applications);

        }
    }
}
```

**Applications.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace PostGraduate.Models.Application
{
    public class Applications
    {

        public Applications()
        {
            this.Addresses = new HashSet<Addresses>();
            this.PreGradStudies = new HashSet<PreGradStudies>();
            this.ForeignLanguages = new HashSet<ForeignLanguages>();
        }

        internal void BuildAddress(int p)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < p; i++)
            {
                Addresses.Add(new Addresses());
            }
        }

        internal void BuildPreGradStudies (int p)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < p; i++)
            {
                PreGradStudies.Add(new PreGradStudies());
            }
        }

        internal void BuildForeignLanguages(int p)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < p; i++)
            {
                ForeignLanguages.Add(new ForeignLanguages());
            }
        }

        public virtual Users Users { get; set; }
        public virtual Gmat Gmat { get; set; }
        public virtual PostGradStudies PostGradStudies { get; set; }
        public virtual Schoolarships Schoolarships { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Addresses> Addresses { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<PreGradStudies> PreGradStudies { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ForeignLanguages> ForeignLanguages { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public string Applications_Id { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public DateTime ApplicationDate { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string FathersName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public DateTime? Birthdate { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Birthplace { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Identification { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Country { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string MobileNumber { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Profession { get; set; }

        public string Activity { get; set; }

        public string PostGradExtra { get; set; }

        public string PostGradReapplication { get; set; }

        public string ExtraInformation { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string PostGradSource { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Addresses.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace PostGraduate.Models.Application
{
    public class Addresses
    {
        public virtual Applications Applications { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public string Addresses_Id { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public string Application_Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string StreetAddress { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string City { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**ForeignLanguages.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace PostGraduate.Models.Application
{
    public class ForeignLanguages
    {

        public virtual Applications Applications { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public string ForeignLanguages_Id { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public string Application_Id { get; set; }

        public string Language { get; set; }

        public string LanguageDegree { get; set; }

        public string Admission { get; set; }

        public bool Delete { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Gmat.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace PostGraduate.Models.Application
{
    public class Gmat
    {
        public virtual Applications Applications { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public string Gmat_Id { get; set; }

        public DateTime? GmatDate { get; set; }

        public string GmatGrade { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**PostGradStudies.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace PostGraduate.Models.Application
{
    public class PostGradStudies
    {
        public virtual Applications Applications { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public string PostGradStudies_Id { get; set; }

        public string Aei { get; set; }

        public string PostGradTitle { get; set; }

        public string PostGradLength { get; set; }

        public string PostGradGrade { get; set; }

        public string PostGradProject { get; set; }

        public string PostGradProjectGrade { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**PreGradStudies.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace PostGraduate.Models.Application
{
    public class PreGradStudies
    {
        public virtual Applications Applications { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public string PreGradStudies_Id { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public string Application_Id { get; set; }

        public string University { get; set; }

        public string Department { get; set; }

        public string Admission { get; set; }

        public string Graduation { get; set; }

        public string DegreeGrade { get; set; }

        public string ThesisSubject { get; set; }

        public string ThesisGrade { get; set; }

        public bool Delete { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Schoolarships.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace PostGraduate.Models.Application
{
    public class Schoolarships
    {
        public virtual Applications Applications { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public string Schoolarships_Id { get; set; }

        public string Schoolar { get; set; }

        public string SchoolarshipProfession { get; set; }

        public string SchoolarshipInstitution { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Users.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace PostGraduate.Models.Application
{
    public class Users
    {
        public virtual Applications Applications { get; set; }

        public string UserId { get; set; }

        public string UserName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you include your `Application Controller` code also?

But I suspect, that it could be because some of your entities are defined as not having autogenerated Primary Keys, that when they the objects are created, that they will all have the same key.

I would assume all the keys are set as either empty strings or NULL, so when checking for something else with a key of NULL, it would already get a match...

(sorry I don't have the best understanding of EF, but just a thought!)

Answer (score 0):

One of the reason this could happen is if you have the same property twice from your view models. For example, if you have `UserName` on a class and you have it on another class and both are present in your view. That would create a duplicate `UserName` key.

I experienced this when I had two properties with the same name in one class. One a public field member and the other a get/set accessor

```
public class User
{
   public string userName;  // <---- this should be private

   public string UserName
   {
     get { return userName; }
     set { userName = value; }
   }
}
```

Notice C# didn't complain because of case-sensitivity. I solved that by making the field variable `private`